# Macbook connects to modem, internet works, but modem -> router, no internet

Tags: network, wifi, airport, internet

I'm running a netgear modem CG3000D, and have been able to access internet without problems. However my speeds on the internet were slow for gaming and extensive usage, so I purchased a netgear R6250 WiFi router to increase speed and range.

My modem will connect to the router no problem, and my Macbook can connect to the router (with a different WiFi network name now), however there is absolutely no internet access now.

I'm not fluent in Mac operations yet, so I'm not sure what to do or where to go to fix this problem.

I tried airport utility but it can't find the router? Not sure what to do here.

Thanks

Comment: How is the modem connecting to the router.  Wired or Wireless?  You probably need to to connect to the router's web interface and put it into bridge mode, and let the modem act as the dhcp server across your local network.

Answer (score 1):

[Disabling the WiFi Signal on the Netgear CG3000D WiFi Cable Modem](http://www.cox.com/residential/support/internet/article.cox?articleId=358cbe00-3e53-11e2-6147-000000000000)

You may have a standalone router that you would like to continue to use and are having problems with connecting to your router. The device may be causing a conflict because the router portion of the device is also active. You can turn off the WiFi network of the device, turning it into a modem only, and be able to use your router without an issue.

Completing this procedure disables the SSID for the Netgear CG3000D Home Device. This allows customers to use their own standalone wireless router.